# PostgreSQL: Adding an interval to a timestamp in a different time zone

Tags: sql, postgresql, timezone, plpgsql, dst

What is the best way to add a specified interval to a timestamp with time zone, if I don't want to do the calculation in the time zone of the server. This is particularly important around daylight savings transitions.

e.g.
consider the evening that we "spring forward". (Here in Toronto, I think it was 2016-03-13 at 2am).
If I take a time stamp:
`2016-03-13 00:00:00-05`
and add `'1 day'` to it, in Canada/Eastern, I would expect to get `2016-03-14 00:00:00-04` -> 1 day later, but actually only 23 hours
But if I add 1 day to it in Saskatchewan (a place that doesn't use DST), I would want it to add 24 hours, so that I'd end up with 
`2016-03-13 01:00:00-04`.

If I have columns / variables

```
t1 timestamp with time zone;
t2 timestamp with time zone;
step interval; 
zoneid text; --represents the time zone
```

I essentially want to say

```
t2 = t1 + step; --in a time zone of my choosing
```

Postgres documentation seems to indicate that timestamp with time zone is internally stored in UTC time, which seems to indicate that a timestamptz column has no reckoning of a time zone in it.
The SQL standard indicates that
datetime + interval  operation should maintain the time zone of the first operand.

```
t2 = (t1 AT TIME ZONE zoneid + step) AT TIME ZONE zoneid;
```

doesn't seem to work because the first cast turns t1 into a timezone-less timestamp and thus can't reckon DST transitions

```
t2 = t1 + step;
```

doesn't seem to work as it does the operation in the time zone of my SQL server

set the postgres time zone before the operation and change it back after?

A better illustration:

```
CREATE TABLE timestamps (t1 timestamp with time zone, timelocation text);
SET Timezone 'America/Toronto';
INSERT INTO timestamps(t1, timelocation) VALUES('2016-03-13 00:00:00 America/Toronto', 'America/Toronto');
INSERT INTO timestamps(t1, timelocation) VALUES('2016-03-13 00:00:00 America/Regina', 'America/Regina');

SELECT t1, timelocation FROM timestamps; -- shows times formatted in Toronto time. OK
"2016-03-13 00:00:00-05";"America/Toronto"
"2016-03-13 01:00:00-05";"America/Regina"

SELECT t1 + '1 day', timelocation FROM timestamps; -- Toronto timestamp has advanced by 23 hours. OK. Regina time stamp has also advanced by 23 hours. NOT OK.
"2016-03-14 00:00:00-04";"America/Toronto"
"2016-03-14 01:00:00-04";"America/Regina"
```

How to get around this?

a) Cast the timestamptz to a timestamp tz in the appropriate time zone?

```
SELECT t1 AT TIME ZONE timelocation + '1 day', timelocation FROM timestamps; --OK. Though my results are timestamps without time zone now.
"2016-03-14 00:00:00";"America/Toronto"
"2016-03-14 00:00:00";"America/Regina"

SELECT t1 AT TIME ZONE timelocation + '4 hours', timelocation FROM timestamps; -- NOT OK. I want the Toronto time to be 5am
"2016-03-13 04:00:00";"America/Toronto"
"2016-03-13 04:00:00";"America/Regina"
```

b) Change timezone of postgres and proceed.

```
SET TIMEZONE = 'America/Regina';
SELECT t1 + '1 day', timelocation FROM timestamps; -- Now the Regina time stamp is correct, but toronto time stamp is incorrect (should be 22:00-06)
"2016-03-13 23:00:00-06";"America/Toronto"
"2016-03-14 00:00:00-06";"America/Regina"

SET TIMEZONE = 'America/Toronto';
SELECT t1 + '1 day', timelocation FROM timestamps; -- toronto is correct, regina is not, as before
"2016-03-14 00:00:00-04";"America/Toronto"
"2016-03-14 01:00:00-04";"America/Regina"
```

This solution will only work if I continually switch the postgres timezone before every operation time interval operation.

Comment: Edit: The t1 and t2 variables should have been written as "timestamp with time zone". Sorry, I'm new here and can't find the edit button.

Comment: If the answer solved your problem, could you mark it as the accepted answer ? TIA.

Answer (score 9):

It is a combination of two properties that causes your problem:

1. `timestamp with time zone` is stored in UTC and does not contain any time zone information. A better name for it would be “UTC timestamp”.
2. Addition of `timestamp with time zone` and `interval` is always performed in the current time zone, i.e. the one set with the configuration parameter `TimeZone`.

Since what you really need to store is a timestamp and the time zone in which it is valid, you should store a combination of `timestamp without time zone` and a `text` representing the time zone.

As you correctly noticed, you would have to switch the current time zone to perform interval addition over the daylight savings time shift correctly (otherwise PostgreSQL does not know how long `1 day` is).
But you don't have to do that by hand, you can use a PL/pgSQL function to do it for you:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION add_in_timezone(
      ts timestamp without time zone,
      tz text,
      delta interval
   ) RETURNS timestamp without time zone
   LANGUAGE plpgsql IMMUTABLE AS
$$DECLARE
   result timestamp without time zone;
   oldtz text := current_setting('TimeZone');
BEGIN
   PERFORM set_config('TimeZone', tz, true);
   result := (ts AT TIME ZONE tz) + delta;
   PERFORM set_config('TimeZone', oldtz, true);
   RETURN result;
END;$$;
```

That would give you the following, where the result is to be understood in the same time zone as the argument:

```
test=> SELECT add_in_timezone('2016-03-13 00:00:00', 'America/Toronto', '1 day');
   add_in_timezone
---------------------
 2016-03-14 00:00:00
(1 row)

test=> SELECT add_in_timezone('2016-03-13 00:00:00', 'America/Regina', '1 day');
   add_in_timezone
---------------------
 2016-03-14 00:00:00
(1 row)

test=> SELECT add_in_timezone('2016-03-13 00:00:00', 'America/Toronto', '4 hours');
   add_in_timezone
---------------------
 2016-03-13 05:00:00
(1 row)

test=> SELECT add_in_timezone('2016-03-13 00:00:00', 'America/Regina', '4 hours');
   add_in_timezone
---------------------
 2016-03-13 04:00:00
(1 row)
```

You could consider creating a combined type

```
CREATE TYPE timestampattz AS (
   ts timestamp without time zone,
   zone text
);
```

and define operators and casts on it, but that's probably a major project that exceeds what you want for this.

There even is a PostgreSQL extension [timestampandtz](https://github.com/mweber26/timestampandtz) that does exactly that; maybe that's just what you need (I didn't look what the semantics for addition are).

Comment: Thanks Laurenz. Unfortunately I typoed my question. The two variables are indeed timestamp with time zone as you suggested. But the problem still seems to exist.

Comment: Prove it please. How is your use case different from the examples I gave?

Comment: Instead of TIMESTAMPTZ '2016-03-13 00:00:00 CST', insert that value, along with TIMESTAMPTZ '2016-03-13 00:00:00 America/Toronto' into a table with a timestamptz column. Then I need a method to add '1 day' to either of those values, in either a "CST" time frame or a "Toronto" time frame.

Comment: Now I understand, I have modified the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the informations given by @LaurenzAlbe, I used something different to handle adding an interval to a `timestamptz` and using DST. I had the problem this 2020-10-25 since in Belgium (timezone "Europe/Brussels" which is UTC+1) we observe DST and on 2020-10-25 at 03:00 we went backward for 1 hour ending at 02:00, i.e. we went from summer time UTC+2 to winter time UTC+1.

The code below which has to find the `timestamptz` at 16:00 on a given day failed that day and instead ended at 15:00 because we went backward 1h. The problematic line of code was:

```
select date_trunc('day', myfct.datetime) + interval 'PT16H'
```

For example, first query is ok, second is not.

```
select date_trunc('day', timestamptz '2020-10-27 17:00:00+01') + interval 'PT16H';
        ?column?        
------------------------
 2020-10-27 16:00:00+01

select date_trunc('day', timestamptz '2020-10-25 17:00:00+01') + interval 'PT16H';
        ?column?        
------------------------
 2020-10-25 15:00:00+01
```

The idea is to make the addition with a `timestamp` (without time zone) instead of a `timestamptz` and finally convert it to a `timestamptz` with the configured time zone of the database.

```
hydro_dev=> select date_trunc('day', timestamptz '2020-10-25 17:00:00+01');
       date_trunc       
------------------------
 2020-10-25 00:00:00+02
(1 row)

hydro_dev=> select date_trunc('day', timestamptz '2020-10-25 17:00:00+01')::timestamp;
     date_trunc      
---------------------
 2020-10-25 00:00:00
(1 row)

hydro_dev=> select date_trunc('day', timestamptz '2020-10-25 17:00:00+01')::timestamp + interval 'PT16H';
      ?column?       
---------------------
 2020-10-25 16:00:00
(1 row)

select (date_trunc('day', timestamptz '2020-10-25 17:00:00+01')::timestamp + interval 'PT16H')::timestamptz;
      timestamptz       
------------------------
 2020-10-25 16:00:00+01
```